# My computer takes forever to reboot, also seems to take forever to open new windows

Tags: windows-7

I have a computer, I run Windows 7 Ultimate and the computer itself is about 1 year, maybe slightly less old.  It usually takes anywhere from 10 to 30 minutes to reboot, as in until I can actually open up new windows/processes. Anything else runs PERFECTLY normal, as if there are 0 problems.  All of my games still run with flawless performance. It just seems to take AGES to open anything even though my Physical Memory and CPU usage remain at 50% or under most of the time.  I tried many different thinks like cleaning out my computer, deleting programs I don't use, Disk Cleanup, ran multiple anti-virus software. I'm kinda running out of answers. I'd hate to think it's my processor going bad because this computer really isn't that old. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your CrystalDiskInfo health report on your hard drive. You may have bad sectors.

Comment: Sorry, how do I do this?

Comment: Try defrag  to defragment your hdd. From Computer: Select the C: drive and right click properties. Then "Tools" and the "Defragment Now"  Wait up to 4 hours for it to finish.  Reboot and time it.

Comment: Okay, so I did the defrag thing, and as soon as I hit defragment, the window freezes, I can't close it or minimize it unless I do it through the taskbar or task manager.  Is this normal? It's not going up in progress either. It's been this way since about 5 minutes after you suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

[Soluto](http://download.cnet.com/Soluto/3028-18512_4-75446583.html?c=SEM-SEO&s=fivemill&pid=dlcom_sem&aid=soluto%20download-e&dlc=n&part=fivemill)

Download and install "Soluto" from the link.
Make sure to carefully uncheck the free junk cnet attaches.

Reboot, and unfortunately you are going to have to reboot 2 times.

This software will tell you what is taking so long in the boot process.
Screen capture and post the results screen.

A few things will stick out taking multiple minutes.

Then we know what is taking so long.  In the meantime budget for $115 for a 128gb SSD (boot drive only) to make boot times even faster.  You can re-install all your existing software on your hard drive if necessary. Either that or get a bigger SSD.

If you have the time and patients you can use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to deactivate unnecessary start up tasks.

Comment: Stumbled across another problem that's been happening, now when I click a download, particularly this one you linked, it brings up the typical administrator approval window.  I hit accept but the grayed out background doesn't go away for about 10 minutes and I can't interact with the background as if the window was still up, then after the 10 minutes it goes away, but the set-up is not activated.

Comment: @Sierra Ok.  Start button in search type cmd  right click on "command prompt" "run as administrator" chkdsk /r c:   type "y" for yes do this when the system reboots.  Reboot ...wait patiently for chkdsk to run